# Cocoa: NSUserNotification appears behind NSPopover

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nspopover, nsusernotification

I have no idea where to even start trying to fix this but maybe someone can point me in the right direction. I have a status item application that shows a popover when clicked, some user interactions produce an NSUserNotification to warn/inform about changes or errors. But when the notification appears it is shown behind the popover, so if they overlay the user can't read what it says.

Is there a way to force the notification to appear in front of the popover? Like order the notification to the front.

Edit: here's a picture showing part of the notification hidden behind the popover after a user gave bad input. I don't really want to hide the popover to show the error notification.

[image]

I've tried stuff lake makeKeyAndOrderFront, activateIgnoringOtherApps, the type of stuff you'd use on a window, but none of it applies to an NSUserNotification so it doesn't work.

Edit 2: I should note that to get the popover to appear in front of everything when called I use activateIgnoringOtherApps and becomeFirstResponder on the popover, but even getting rid of that still shows the notification behind the popover.

Edit 3: The popover is shown relative to a status item in the status bar using 
`[[self popover] showRelativeToRect:statusItem.view.bounds ofView:statusItem.view preferredEdge:NSMaxYEdge];`
 
When clicked, the status item calls a method that does this:

```
- (void)openPopover:(id)sender {
if (![_popover isShown] | (_popoverIsClosing)) {
    [_preferencesWindow close];
    [NSApp activateIgnoringOtherApps:YES];
    [_popover becomeFirstResponder];
    [statusItemView setHighlighted:YES];
    [[self popover] showRelativeToRect:statusItem.view.bounds ofView:statusItem.view preferredEdge:NSMaxYEdge];
    [self performSelector:@selector(defaultTextField)];
    NSLog(@"popover opened");

} else {
    [_preferencesWindow close];
    [NSApp activateIgnoringOtherApps:NO];
    NSLog(@"popover closed");
    [_popover close];
    [_popover resignFirstResponder];
    [[NSApplication sharedApplication] hide: self];
    [statusItemView setHighlighted:NO];
}
```

}

Thanks for the help.

Comment: I'm guessing this is probably related to the window level in the popover's window, can you share some more about how you're displaying that popover?

Comment: Edit 3 has more information

Comment: you are positioning an `NSPopover` on an item in the menu bar, which has a higher level than notifications.

Comment: Meaning there is no way to fix this? Can I temporarily change the level of the status item or the notification?

Comment: How about `[[[_popover.contentViewController view] window] setLevel:level]`? I've not tested though.

Comment: @rintaro That worked! Write it up in an answer and I'll select it as the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You want to adjust the `window.level`.

A notification is using level 18, so as long as your level is lower, you will not have this issue.

You can use these default `NSWindow.Level`

- `.normal` = 0
- `.floating` = 3
- `.submenu` = 3
- `.tornOffMenu` = 3

Or a custom level `NSWindow.Level(rawValue: 17)`.

An important thing to note is you should set the windows level during or after the popover did show. Otherwise your setting will be reset.

You can do this from the `popover.delegate` using the function,

```
func popoverDidShow(_ notification: Notification)
```

Or listen to the notification directly with `NSPopoverDidShowNotification`.

This has been tested on macOS 10.15